# Factoring a joint posterior

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, posterior, joint-distribution, distributions

Suppose the joint posterior density for parameters $(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ can be expressed as 
\begin{align} \Pr(\theta_1, \theta_2 \mid y) &\propto Pr(y \mid \theta_1, \theta_2) *Pr(\theta_1, \theta_2)\\
&=Pr(y \mid \theta_1, \theta_2) *Pr(\theta_1 \mid \theta_2)*Pr(\theta_2)
\end{align}
These 2 forms are equivalent, right? Then, can we factor and express the joint posterior as:
\begin{align} 
\Pr(\theta_1, \theta_2 \mid y) &= (\Pr(\theta_1 \mid \theta_2, y)*Pr(\theta_2 \mid y)) \\
&\propto Pr(y \mid \theta_1, \theta_2) *Pr(\theta_1 \mid \theta_2) * Pr(\theta_2 \mid y) \\
&\propto Pr(y \mid \theta_1, \theta_2) *Pr(\theta_1 \mid \theta_2)*Pr(y \mid \theta_2 )* Pr(\theta_2) 
\end{align}

I think I followed the rules of factorization but because of $Pr(y \mid \theta_2)$ I can't equate the first derivation with the second up to a proportionality constant.
$$ Pr(y \mid \theta_1, \theta_2) *Pr(\theta_1 \mid \theta_2)*Pr(\theta_2)
\propto Pr(y \mid \theta_1, \theta_2) *Pr(\theta_1 \mid \theta_2)*Pr(y \mid \theta_2 )* Pr(\theta_2) $$

Can someone point me where I made a mistake?

Comment: In your second equation, I don't see how you can write $Pr(\theta_1|\theta_2,y)$ as being proportional to $Pr(y | \theta_1, \theta_2) \; * \; Pr(\theta_1 | \theta_2)$.

Comment: Yes I see, I've fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Vimal points out my mistake was writing, 
$$Pr(\theta_1 \mid \theta_2, y)*Pr(\theta_2 \mid y) \propto Pr(y \mid \theta_1, \theta_2) *Pr(\theta_1 \mid \theta_2) * Pr(\theta_2 \mid y)$$
When factoring, 
\begin{align} 
(\Pr(\theta_1 \mid \theta_2, y)*Pr(\theta_2 \mid y)) &= \Pr(\theta_1 \mid \theta_2, y)*Pr(\theta_2 \mid y) \\
&= \dfrac{Pr(y \mid \theta_1, \theta_2) *Pr(\theta_1 \mid \theta_2)}{Pr(y \mid \theta_2)} * Pr(\theta_2 \mid y) \\
&= \dfrac{Pr(y \mid \theta_1, \theta_2) *Pr(\theta_1 \mid \theta_2)}{Pr(y \mid \theta_2)} * \dfrac{Pr(y \mid \theta_2) Pr(\theta_2)}{Pr(y)} \\
&\propto Pr(y \mid \theta_1, \theta_2) *Pr(\theta_1 \mid \theta_2) * Pr(\theta_2)
\end{align}
Thus, both approaches factoring the prior and factoring the posterior are equivalent.